# How do you test for the non-existence of anchor element using jest and react-testing-library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

My react component renders a link based on a rule.

The mark up is rendered as such when there is a link within the h4 element.

```
<h4><a href="">foo</a></h4>
<p>blah blah <a href="">bar</a> blah blah</p>
```

This is my how test is written to verify a link exist.

```
  const props = {
    heading: 'foo',
    headingLink: '//www.bar.com',
  }

  test('render the heading text with link', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<Component {...props} />)
    getByText(props.heading)
    expect(getByText(props.heading).getAttribute('href')).toBe(props.headingLink)
  })
```

How would I test that the anchor element isn't rendered/doesn't exist in the h4?

```
<h4>foo</h4>
<p>blah blah <a href="">bar</a> blah blah</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a `data-testid` attribute to the anchor tag and use a `queryBy*` query and assert the value is `null`.

[Queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet#queries)

[image]

From [What queries should I use?](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#priority)

> **Test IDs**
>
> `getByTestId`: The user cannot see (or hear) these, so this is only
> recommended for cases where you can't match by role or text ***or it
> doesn't make sense (e.g. the text is dynamic)***.

In your case the anchor tag is dynamic.

Given `<h4><a data-testid="test" href="">foo</a></h4>` or `<h4>foo</h4>`.

Test Case:

```
const { queryByTestId } = render(<Component {...props} />);

expect(queryByTestId('test')).toBe(null);
```

### Update

There are also [Manual Queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#manual-queries) using a `container` and the `querySelector` DOM API. It may look something like this.*****

Given `<h4><a href="">foo</a></h4>` or `<h4>foo</h4>`.

Test Case:

```
const { container } = render(<Component {...props} />);

expect(container.querySelector('h4 > a')).toBe(null);
```

***** *I've not ever tested like this, but according to the docs this should be very close to what you may be looking for.*

Comment: Is there an alternative? I don't want to add extra attributes simply for testing purposes.

Comment: @calebo I believe so. You can use regular DOM querySelector on the `container` render option. I added an example for what I think could work for you.

Comment: Thanks Drew. Second querySelector option worked.